# postgresql stored procedure begin commit end

Tags: postgresql

I'm actually very confused when performing postgresql stored procedure (I learned the below from somewhere):

```
create or replace procedure update_dba_trades ()
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    [CODE BLOCK WITH INSERT DELETE ETC...]
    commit;

end;
$$
```

Why do we use all begin, end and commit? My understanding of postgresql is "end" is the same as "commit"

```
begin;
[code block]
end;
```

represents one complete transaction (either all failed or all succeed). I don't need to `begin; [code]; commit; end;`

However, I have difficulties trying to implement multiple independent code blocks. In PostgreSQL, I could do

```
begin;
[code block1]
end;
begin;
[code block2]
end;
```

Then [code block1] can succeed even if [code block 2] failed and wise versa. If I do,

```
create or replace procedure update_dba_trades ()
language plpgsql
as $$
begin;
[code block1]
end;
begin;
[code block2]
end;
$$
```

Then there is error. How do I achieve multiple independent code block? Thanks!

Comment: `begin` and `end` are just blocks in pl/pgsql. They have nothing to do with transactions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't mix up the [SQL statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) `BEGIN` (synonymous with `START TRANSACTION`) and `END` (synonymous with `COMMIT`) with the [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) syntax elements `BEGIN` and `END`.

In PL/pgSQL, code is arranged in *blocks* that look [like this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html):

> ```
> [ <<label>> ]
> [ DECLARE
>     declarations ]
> BEGIN
>     statements
> END [ label ];
> ```

`BEGIN` and `END` are not statements here, they are rather like `{` and `}` in programming languages like C or Java and indentation in Python.

You can use transaction control SQL statements in a PL/pgSQL procedure, but you cannot explicitly start a transaction, since you are already in one, so the `BEGIN` SQL statement is not allowed. A new transaction is automatically started in PL/pgSQL if you end the previous one, which has to be done with `COMMIT` (`END` is not allowed as synonym for `COMMIT` in PL/pgSQL).

Comment: Thanks so much, i guessed there is no way to achieve ` begin;
[code block1]
end;
begin;
[code block2]
end;` in plpgsql?

Comment: Sure you can, if you omit the semicolons after `BEGIN`. But these are blocks, it has nothing to do with transaction management..